# How to add Spinner on NavigationView

Tags: android, menuitem, navigationview

How to add Spinner on NavigationView list? Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, now its possible with android support version 23.1+, See this official [blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html).

1.First create a xml layout *spinner_menu.xml* with a spinner item

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</Spinner>
```

2.Than link it to the navigation view menu xml like this

```
<item android:id="@+id/nav_lang"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
     android:title="Language"
     app:actionLayout="@layout/spinner_menu"/>
```

3.If you want to access it in your activity, like add action when spinner item is selected,

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id. nav_lang).getActionView();
    sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,langs));
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,langs[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Where **langs** is a string array or array list to display items in spinner.

It will look something like below,

[image]

Hope it will help you buddy!.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. A NavigationView ultimately extends from FrameLayout so your layout could be setup as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Content View - include your main layout here -->
<include layout="@layout/activity_main" />

<!-- Drawer view -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- TODO Add Spinner views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```